# SharePoint Workflow Designer Update List Item

Tags: workflow

I want to update a list item in a SharePoint document library. I have a folder and I want to update a specific folder value. I have the folder GUID. Can I update property of folder by finding the specific folder by folder GUID?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use "Update List Item"; this will allow you to filter the item based on a field.

[image: Update List Item dialog box]

Comment: I tried already but this is not working.

Comment: In value I have given guid {xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}